# Django admin foreign key dropdown with custom value

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have 3 Django models:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    pass

class Page(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)

class Question(model.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
```

If I register the `Question` model to the admin, I get a dropdown with the desired `Page`. Now, what do I have to modify to display the desired `Page` **plus** that page's corresponding `Test`?

Say, if I have three pages created, the dropdown will contain these values: `Page1`, `Page2`, `Page3`. I would like to see: `Page1 - Test1`, `Page2 - Test1`, `Page3 - Test1`

Comment: Do you want to display this in the admin list page?

Comment: I would like to display this in the question add/edit page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2 Options.

Option 1:

Create a new `field`, copy `forms.ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`.

```
# From the source
class PageModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField():
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        """
        This method is used to convert objects into strings; it's used to
        generate the labels for the choices presented by this object. Subclasses
        can override this method to customize the display of the choices.
        """
        # Then return what you'd like to display
        return "Page{0} - Test{1}".format(obj.pk, obj.test.pk)
```

This will only change the text for that particular dropdown field.  As you are accessing the `Test` object for each item in the list, you may want to ensure the `queryset` you pass to the `PageModelChoiceField` has `select_related('test')`, otherwise it will make a DB hit for each item on the list.

*I've not tested this exact code but the logic is there.  Will try it later when I can*

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    page = PageModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Page.objects.select_related('test').all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Page


class QuestionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        form = QuestionForm
```

---

Option B.

Change the **unicode**() representation of `Page`.

```
class Page(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Page{0} - Test{1}".format(obj.pk, obj.test.pk)
```

This will change how `Page`s are displayed everywhere you print a page object, `print(page_object)`, `{{ page_object }}`.

---

Personally I prefer Option 1

Comment: Happy to help.  I always prefer full answers so thought it best to provide them myself as well :)

Comment: Thank you.. Option B made my day.. used 'self.<var>' instead of 'obj.pk'

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Option B in the accepted answer didn't work for me so I figured I'd update this page with what worked well for me.

You can overload the __str__ function for the Page model to get what you're wanting. So, something along the lines of this

```
class Page(models.Model):
   test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
   def __str__(self):
      return f'Page{self.pk} - Test{self.test.pk}'
```

Comment: The reason this answer got downvoted is that it suggest universally overriding the string representation of the model instance. I believe the question implies that they only want the string representation to be custom in the admin/